# vba loop through row and iterate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data which represents failure frequencies dependance on nominal pipe diameter.See the table below.(in first row are nominal diameters - DN and in the 2nd one are failure frequencies for each DN)

50, 150, 300, 450, 600, 900

3.8E-05, 1.7E-05, 1.6E-05, 1.5E-05, 1.5E-05, 1.5E-05

What I need to do is loop through this data and calculate appropriate failure frequency for chosen DN (outside of table), let's say DN 200.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two built in functions that do what you want - VLOOKUP to lookup a value from a vertical list and HLOOKUP to lookup a value from a horizontal list. Your lookup is horizontal so use HLOOKUP.

The parameters are as follows:

```
=HLOOKUP(value, table_array, row_index)
```

Where value is the value you want to lookup, table array is the range of the lookup table and row_index is the row in the table that contains the result.

If you wanted to look up the value for 200 and your table is at D3 to I4 and the value to lookup is in row number 2 you would use the following formula

```
=HLOOKUP(200, D3:I4, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is handy function. But what if I have only 150 and then 300 diameter and want to converge between corresponding frequencies and calculate frequency for diameter 200.

Answer (score 0):

To do a linear interpolation to find the value y for a number x that is not in the lookup you need calculate the following values

The next lowest x value, xlower

The next lowest y value, ylower

The next highest x value, xhigher

The next highest y value, yhigher

y then becomes

```
y=ylower + (((x-xlower)/(xhigher-xlower))*(yhigher-ylower))
```

you can calculate each of these without resorting to vba

`xlower = HLOOKUP(x,[lookuptable],1)`  hlookup will return the next lowest value if it doesn't find the exact value

```
ylower = HLOOKUP(x,[lookuptable],2)

index_of_next_highest = MATCH(xlower, [range of x values] + 1)

xhigher = INDEX([range of x values],index_of_next_highest)

yhigher = INDEX([range of y values],index_of_next_highest)
```